# Why my image svg doesnt display when i deployed on github

Tags: image, github, svg, console, display

My image svg is not show on my site when is deploy on github but in the code we can see the image svg.

I would know what is a probleme

my site : https://oussous-abdelhadi.github.io/snap/
my depot : https://github.com/Oussous-Abdelhadi/snap

[view local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSFED.png)

[view online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkJwv.png)

[result consol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpzmj.png)